# WASCE to Tomcat migration - Axis fault issue

Tags: tomcat, soap, websphere, apache-axis, websphere-ce

I am working on to converting the WASCE web application into tomcat web application. In my application, I am using the SOAP web services too. When I tried to migrating to tomcat application, I am getting the following exception.

```
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet - init - DEBUG line 111 - In AxisServletBase init
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet - getEngine - DEBUG line 166 - Enter: getEngine()
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle - getBundle - DEBUG line 264 - getBundle(org.apache.axis,org.apache.axis.i18n,resource,null,...)
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle - loadBundle - DEBUG line 423 - loadBundle: Ignoring MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.apache.axis.resource, locale en_US
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle - getBundle - DEBUG line 318 - Created org.apache.axis.i18n.resource, linked to parent null
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle - getBundle - DEBUG line 264 - getBundle(org.apache.axis,org.apache.axis.utils,resource,null,...)
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle - loadBundle - DEBUG line 423 - loadBundle: Ignoring MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.apache.axis.utils.resource, locale en_US
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle - loadBundle - DEBUG line 423 - loadBundle: Ignoring MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.apache.axis.resource, locale en_US
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle - getBundle - DEBUG line 328 - Root package not found, cross link to org.apache.axis.i18n.resource
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle - getBundle - DEBUG line 328 - Root package not found, cross link to org.apache.axis.i18n.resource
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle - handleGetObject - DEBUG line 72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(engineFactory)
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryFinder - run - DEBUG line 141 - Got EngineFactory: org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory - getServer - DEBUG line 71 - Enter: DefaultAxisServerFactory::getServer
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory - getEngineConfiguration - DEBUG line 122 - Enter: DefaultAxisServerFactory::getEngineConfiguration
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory - getEngineConfiguration - DEBUG line 162 - Exit: DefaultAxisServerFactory::getEngineConfiguration
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.AxisEngine - init - DEBUG line 165 - Enter: AxisEngine::init
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle - handleGetObject - DEBUG line 72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(attachEnabled)
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils - isAttachmentSupported - DEBUG line 1305 - Attachment support is enabled?  false
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle - handleGetObject - DEBUG line 72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(attachDisabled)
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils - isAttachmentSupported - WARN line 1308 - Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle - handleGetObject - DEBUG line 72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(oddDigits00)
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle - handleGetObject - DEBUG line 72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(badChars01)
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle - handleGetObject - DEBUG line 72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(exception00)
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseSerializerFactory - createFactory - DEBUG line 261 - Exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.ArraySerializerFactory.create(java.lang.Class, javax.xml.namespace.QName)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseSerializerFactory.createFactory(BaseSerializerFactory.java:254)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.deployTypeMapping(WSDDService.java:542)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.initTMR(WSDDService.java:253)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.<init>(WSDDService.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.<init>(WSDDDeployment.java:192)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.setDocument(WSDDDocument.java:139)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.<init>(WSDDDocument.java:65)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.configureEngine(FileProvider.java:179)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.init(AxisEngine.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.<init>(AxisEngine.java:156)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.<init>(AxisServer.java:88)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.createServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:109)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.getServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.getServer(AxisServer.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getEngine(AxisServletBase.java:185)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getOption(AxisServletBase.java:396)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.init(AxisServletBase.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3988)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle - handleGetObject - DEBUG line 72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(exception00)
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseDeserializerFactory - createFactory - DEBUG line 232 - Exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.ArrayDeserializerFactory.create(java.lang.Class, javax.xml.namespace.QName)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseDeserializerFactory.createFactory(BaseDeserializerFactory.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.deployTypeMapping(WSDDService.java:554)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.initTMR(WSDDService.java:253)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.<init>(WSDDService.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.<init>(WSDDDeployment.java:192)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.setDocument(WSDDDocument.java:139)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.<init>(WSDDDocument.java:65)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.configureEngine(FileProvider.java:179)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.init(AxisEngine.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.<init>(AxisEngine.java:156)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.<init>(AxisServer.java:88)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.createServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:109)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.getServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.getServer(AxisServer.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getEngine(AxisServletBase.java:185)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getOption(AxisServletBase.java:396)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.init(AxisServletBase.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3988)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle - handleGetObject - DEBUG line 72 - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(exception00)
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseDeserializerFactory - createFactory - DEBUG line 253 - Exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.ArrayDeserializerFactory.<init>(java.lang.Class, javax.xml.namespace.QName)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2706)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseDeserializerFactory.createFactory(BaseDeserializerFactory.java:246)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.deployTypeMapping(WSDDService.java:554)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.initTMR(WSDDService.java:253)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.<init>(WSDDService.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.<init>(WSDDDeployment.java:192)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.setDocument(WSDDDocument.java:139)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.<init>(WSDDDocument.java:65)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.configureEngine(FileProvider.java:179)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.init(AxisEngine.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.<init>(AxisEngine.java:156)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.<init>(AxisServer.java:88)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.createServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:109)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.getServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.getServer(AxisServer.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getEngine(AxisServletBase.java:185)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getOption(AxisServletBase.java:396)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.init(AxisServletBase.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3988)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
05:53:47 org.apache.axis.AxisEngine - init - DEBUG line 195 - Exit: AxisEngine::init
```

When I deploy the war in server, I got this exception. When I try to access the web service method I got "Axis Fault : Invocation Target Exception". But it works in WASCE server.

I did change the new axis jar as well. But it didn't work. Can anybody give me a solution for this?

Comment: You should consider migrating to WebSphere Liberty, as Tomcat is just webcontainer and you will have many issues solving library problems.